How to escape string for Typst
What characters should I escape in a string to safely insert in Typst table cell: [my_string].
One way of dealing with this would be to use raw text. The string shouldn't obviously include triple backticks. And the font becomes monospaced.
``` my_string ```


You can simply add an additional set of brackets:
#table([[My text]])
// Or with content-style function call:
// #table[[My text]]

If you wanted to use raw strings, the text field has the unstyled content:
#table(`[My text]`.text) // Same result



I'd like to escape all the characters that have special meaning, not just square brackets. For example, [[ My $text ]] won't compile.

In that case, the backtick solution will work, and \ can be used in content mode to escape individual characters
